# Front End for Java App - Not Swing then JQuery or Jerry?

Tags: java, jquery, swing, user-interface, frontend

I'm new to Java frond end technologies. If we want to develop a cross platform java app and the look and feel should be like somewhat JQuery UI. If we don't want to use swing or Nimbus for front end, then what is the best option to achieve the JQuery UI look? I guess we can't use JQuery, as the app is a cross platform one.  (must be running on linux, Solaris and Mobile) what you suggest?

Is Jerry can be a good option? (I never tried this thing. Find it [here](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Jerry" appears to be mimicing basic jQuery, not jQuery-ui.

Comment: And Nimbus is just Swing with a different PLAF (pluggable look and feel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a cross-platform client side application there are basically three good (mature, proven, well-supported) options in Java:

- Use Swing with pluggable look & feels to get the exact look you want. [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html) is an example of a Swing look and feel, but there are many more. You can also create your own custom look and feels - this is quite a lot of work but does give you the flexibility to define exactly the look that you want. Swing is part of the standard Java distribution and behaves pretty much the same on all platforms, so if portability is your biggest concern, the Swing is a solid choice.
- Use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) which is the GUI toolkit from Eclipse. It's a great toolkit, though does have some native dependencies so you *might* have issues on mobile. SWT provides more of a "native" look and feel to each platform that you run it on.
- Use JavaFX 2.0 which is the relatively new rich client framework from Oracle. Probably more suitable for graphical / rich media apps. Supports CSS-like styling which could be useful.

I'm not really familiar with Jerry, but it looks more like a DOM manipulation library rather than a GUI toolkit so I don't think it will help you much (unless you decide to move away from a client GUI and instead build a web-based front end).

Comment: In recent year there are tremendous changes happening in front end scenarios. For Java, now one best front end framework for Java is JSF (Java Server Faces). Along with libraries like 'Primefaces', it can make life easier and better for developers. This will go well with springs framework too.  

If you are using Struts, another option is to use Twitter Bootstrap based UI components. One library is already build upon Bootstrap - https://code.google.com/p/struts2-bootstrap/